How to debug @FormParam in intelliji
We have an api with below code and I have verified the actual file is being sent as part of the request but the method param "MultipartFile file" is resolving to null.  How can I debug this?  I've looked at the library and I dont see the code that makes that happen.
public void doStuff(@FormParam("file") MultipartFile file)


This method is from where? How is this related to Spring / Spring Boot as the annotation is from JAX-RS not Spring.
